# I want my AngularJS response interceptor to have access to the un-transformed response

Tags: angularjs, interceptor

I have an $http response interceptor, and I want to have access in the interceptor function to the raw response object--*not* the return value of transformResponse. Is this possible?

A little background: every response gets wrapped in a JSON object containing various metadata such as API version, detailed status information, etc. My transformResponse method strips out this wrapper and returns only the actual response payload, because I don't want the various controllers and services to be using this metadata.

However, I would like to have interceptors that do things like complain if the API version is incorrect, or handle various abnormal status conditions, so they need access to that metadata.